# Include mapping table property reference with LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first-mapping

I have following Schema in EF Code First Architecture.

Class Teacher

```
public class Teacher
{
[Key]
public int Teacher_PK { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }        
public virtual ICollection<TeacherClassroom> TeacherClassroom { get; set; } // I have added this to access classroom class's property
}
```

Class Classroom

```
public class Classroom
{
[Key]
public int Classroom_PK { get; set; }
public string ClassName { get; set; }
public int ClassStrength { get; set; }
}
```

I have made a table to establish relationship b/w those tables.

```
public class TeacherClassroom
{
[Key]
public int TecherClassroom_PK { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Teacher_FK")]
public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

[Required]
public int Teacher_FK { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Classroom_FK")]
public virtual Classroom Classroom { get; set; }

[Required]
public int Classroom_FK { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to access Classroom class's property from Teacher class, for that I have added a virtual `ICollection<TeacherClassroom>` in Teacher class, but I can not get the data of classroom class's property.

So far I have tried follwing

```
var teacher = await _context.Teacher.Include(c=>c.TeacherClassroom.Select(y=>y.Classroom))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Teacher_PK == id);
```

In the above Sentence I am getting Classroom Property as `null`.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to incude both levels:

```cs
_context.Teacher.Include(c => c.TeacherClassroom)
                .ThenInclude(tc => tc.Classroom)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Teacher_PK == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var teacher = await _context.Teacher.SelectMany(m=> m.TeacherClassroom).FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Teacher_PK == id);
```

Can you try?

"The SelectMany() keyword creates a new collection as a result of combining the two collections according to the common fields"

Comment: This will give me ```TeacherClassroom``` type, I need ```Teacher``` type as result.